# How to tell `complete` to fall-back to its default?

Tags: python, bash, bash-completion

I'm using the `complete` bash-builtinin to enable arbitrary auto-completion for my python script. I set it up with:

```
complete -C './script.py --compgen "$@"' ./script.py
```

Such that whenever bash attempts to auto-complete it invokes my script with a flag `--compgen` that tells my script to do auto completion. This works fine.

However I want to be able to fall-back to bash's default behaviour in some situations from within `script.py`. Is there a way to tell `complete` that it should rerun without calling my script and do its default-thing instead?

Basically, I want to avoid re-implementing file-name expansion, when referring to a file.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but can't you just use `compgen -o default` in your script?

Comment: I could if I had thought of that. Sometimes it's the super face-palmy solutions that you miss. Care to extend it to an answer? Not sure how to call a bash-builtin from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the fallback of outputting the `compgen` from the python script, has the drawback that it is unescaped. So, if the user tries to complete a file-name like `a/b/c d.txt` the command line will change from:

```bash
./script.py a/b/c\ d.txt
```

to

```bash
./script.py a/b/c d.txt
```

after hitting tab. Other expansions break as well. **The `complete` builtin does offer a fallback**, however:

```bash
complete -C './script.py --compgen "$@"' -o default ./script.py
#                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What this does is tell complete to try the `-C` portion first and if that part returns zero matches, it asks default completion, which then does file-name resolution etc.

I found that one can even force complete to not offer any suggestions by returning exactly the empty string as a suggestion. This prevents the fallback from being run, but it also does not count as an actual suggestion to complete, so it doesn't consider the empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your Python code:

```
import os
# if failed:
os.system("bash -c 'compgen -o default'")
```

Comment: Apparently it breaks for more complex examples as spaces et al. are not properly escaped.